# I need help simplifying this program

Tags: c#

```
        decimal sum;
        int index;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers you want to calculate:");
        string Expression = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Expression.Contains("+"))
        {
            index = Expression.IndexOf("+");
            int secondnumber = index + 1;
            decimal a = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(0, index));
            decimal b = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(secondnumber));
            sum = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Expression, sum.ToString("0.###"));
        } else if (Expression.Contains("-"))
        {
            index = Expression.IndexOf("-");
            int secondnumber = index + 1;
            decimal a = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(0, index));
            decimal b = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(secondnumber));
            sum = a - b;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Expression, sum.ToString("0.###"));
        } else if (Expression.Contains("/"))
        {
            index = Expression.IndexOf("/");
            int secondnumber = index + 1;
            decimal a = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(0, index));
            decimal b = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(secondnumber));
            sum = a / b;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Expression, sum.ToString("0.###"));
        } else if (Expression.Contains("*"))
        {
            index = Expression.IndexOf("*");
            int secondnumber = index + 1;
            decimal a = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(0, index));
            decimal b = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(secondnumber));
            sum = a * b;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Expression, sum.ToString("0.###"));
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        }
```

The problem is that I can't simplify the code without it messing up and it throwing exceptions. Any help would be appreciated.I also need help with the .IndexOf method is there anyway of doing it outside the if selection? I have treied to but it keeps messing up.

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all "if blocks" follow the same pattern:

- Split on an operator of 1 character
- Parse the decimal to the left and the decimal to the right of the operator
- Perform a function on them

you could store the functions in a `Dictionary`:

```
var functionsByOperator = new Dictionary<char, Func<decimal, decimal, decimal>>();
functionsByOperator['+'] = (left, right) => left + right;
functionsByOperator['*'] = (left, right) => left * right;
// etc
```

Then the rest of the code becomes less repetetive:

```
// the below array is required for the IndexOfAny method later on
char[] operators = new List<char>(functionsByOperator.Keys).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers you want to calculate:");
string Expression = Console.ReadLine();

int index = Expression.IndexOfAny(operators);
if (index < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
    return;
}

decimal a = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(0, index));
decimal b = decimal.Parse(Expression.Substring(index + 1));
char oper = Expression[index];
decimal sum = functionsByOperator[oper](a, b);
Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Expression, sum.ToString("0.###"));
```